# using Python venv from script

Tags: python, virtualenv

After creating the virtual environment, If you have a shell script which calls:

```
/home/user/venv/python3 <scriptname>
```

How does it know where the virtualenv's site-packages folder is without source activating into the virtualenv (thus changing the path)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This magic happens with [`sys.prefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.prefix).

> Note: If a virtual environment is in effect, this value will be changed in `site.py` to point to the virtual environment. The value for the Python installation will still be available, via `base_prefix`.

The `site` module is imported (from system path!) at interpreter startup, and the [site-packages dirs are appended to `sys.path` with the `sys.prefix`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ee566fe526f3d069aa313578ee81ca6cbc25ff52/Lib/site.py#L484-L485).

You can verify this for yourself by executing the python REPL with the `-S` flag to disable importing the site module.  You'll find that packages installed in the virtualenv are no longer visible by import statements (assuming they aren't already installed in system site-packages).

Your next question is probably "But how does site itself know if we're in a venv or not?" and the answer is [heuristic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#venv-def):

> A virtual environment is a directory tree which contains Python executable files and other files which indicate that it is a virtual environment.

If a file named "pyvenv.cfg" exists one directory above `sys.executable`,
`sys.prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix` are set to that directory.  Implemented [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ee566fe526f3d069aa313578ee81ca6cbc25ff52/Lib/site.py#L446-L466).

Answer (score 3):

Python looks through the values in `sys.path` for site-packages and these values are automatically set when you execute `python3` or `python` by the `site` package.  Which, is imported during initialization (unless suppressed via the `-S` flag)

You can refer to the [`site`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/site.html) package documentation for more details about how exactly this is done.