# Install dependencies in pipx virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, python-venv, pipx

So I wanted to install ipython with pipx such that I could have an ipython environment that is used anywhere I launch ipython from.

For example let's say I don't want to install any global pip packages. I tried pipx install ipython. Went into the venv pipx created for ipython, and activated it. I hoped that I could then run pip install numpy and that it would only install it in that venv (and then numpy would be available in ipython, but not python).

However it seems to still be installed globally (despite the venv being activated), and is available to python and not ipython (the exact opposite of what I was going for)

How can I achieve the isolation that I am looking for? I thought that was the whole point of pipx

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for `pipx inject ipython numpy`

[Example in the pipx docs](https://pypa.github.io/pipx/examples/#pipx-inject-example)

Answer (score 0):

Found a useful post here: [Why does pip list not work correctly within a virtual environment created by pipx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64217423/why-does-pip-list-not-work-correctly-within-a-virtual-environment-created-by-pip)

Just need to run `python -m pip install` instead of `pip install` after activating the venv